# How to turn a python dictionary into a list with intentionally duplicate values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary in the following form:

```
{'string1': 3, 'string2': 4, 'string3':2}
```

I want to turn it into a list with instances of the key as a function of its corresponding value pair. Like so:

```
['string1','string1','string1','string2','string2','string2','string2','string3','string3']
```

I am having an annoyingly difficult time figuring this out, as I feel there should be an elegant solution. Here's what I have so far:

```
t2 = [dictionary[key]*key for key in dictionary.keys()]
```

but that yields the following mess:

```
['string2string2string2string2', 'string3string3', 'string1string1string1']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this, if the order of the keys is not important:

```
[k for k, v in d.items() for _ in range(v)]

#['string2',
# 'string2',
# 'string2',
# 'string2',
# 'string3',
# 'string3',
# 'string1',
# 'string1',
# 'string1']
```

Comment: Yup, there is the incredibly elegant answer that I somehow couldn't think up. Thanks Psidom!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `collections.Counter()` to do this:

```
>>> list(Counter(d).elements())
['string1', 'string1', 'string1', 'string3', 'string3', 'string2', 'string2', 'string2', 'string2']
```

Of course with a dictionary, order is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you messed up was you forgot to put key in square brackets, here:

```
dictionary = {'string1': 3, 'string2': 4, 'string3':2}
t2 = [dictionary[key]*[key] for key in dictionary.keys()]
print(t2)
```

result:

```
[['string2', 'string2', 'string2', 'string2'], ['string1', 'string1', 'string1'], ['string3', 'string3']]
```

*** EDIT ***

If you want a flattened version here's the modified code for that:

```
t2 = [''.join(j) for j in [[i]for arr in [dictionary[key]*[key] for key in dictionary.keys()] for i in arr]]
```

result:

```
['string3', 'string3', 'string2', 'string2', 'string2', 'string2', 'string1', 'string1', 'string1']
```

Comment: You still need to flatten it. The Itertools module has some functions to do that. Apart from that it is good